# How can I save a Django field (as in the field object) to the database?

Tags: django, field

I'm trying to implement a reusable form that users can download the source code in HTML which was site generated for them by the site. They can also create their forms using an interface where they get to choose the fields they want and rank them so the highest would appear first in the downloadable form.

They can then use the form in their sites to gather customer data and when the form gets submitted, the action parameter points back to our site so we can store the information on our servers.

**Now, my question is, how can I save a Django Field object in my database?** This is so I can store the forms that the users created, especially the Fields that they chose.

I need to store the Fields so that I can create a generic Django ModelForm and the users can save the Fields of that ModelForm in their downloadable forms. So when they submit back the information to us I can feed the information straight to the ModelForm (since the Fields would be recognizable) and do some further validation.

Also I have to add some basic javascript validations (like validation.js) for each field (must be present when the user downloads the form), and I know it will be easier if I can save the Fields themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You could pickle the Field object:

```
import cPickle
field = forms.CharField()
dump = cPickle.dumps(field) # serializes field as an ASCII string
my_model.stored_field = dump
```

To unpickle:

```
field = cPickle.loads(my_model.stored_field)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html